# Can't extract PostHistory from stack overflow data dumps

Tags: bug, data-dump, error-message

I downloaded the stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z file from [here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and I can't extract the 7z file. I tried 7-zip software and WinRAR. I also tried extracting from 2 different hard drives. Both failed.

I got the following error in 7-zip when I tried to extract:

> Data error (cyclic redundancy check).

The error appeared after about 50% of extraction like in this picture:

[image: Extracting error]

Comment: It is a *massive* file, and I wonder if its simply a matter of it not being completed

Comment: Most often this is an issue with the drive, could simply be a bad sector, try running windows error checker on it https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disk-error-checking-windows-8

Comment: If you download the https://ia800107.us.archive.org/27/items/stackexchange/stackexchange_files.xml you'll find the md5, crc and sha1 hashes of that *stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z* file: `<md5>88dc03071223959a1ba4ce74b1acd06c</md5>`
`<crc32>24fb13cb</crc32>`
`<sha1>c51c4886f7477365fa1a687b1c3e04b4bd6c96ac</sha1>` which you can compare with the hashes that you generate for your local file. If they differ you know your local bytes are incorrect.

Comment: @rene can you please explain to me what i need to compare with the hashes you provided?

Comment: @MarkKirby I tried your solution with both drives, windows did not find a thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it just stopped extracting, keeping me with about 50% of the content of the file

Comment: see for how to get the hash of your local file https://superuser.com/questions/699014/how-to-make-sure-a-downloaded-iso-matches-a-hash-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a solution to my problem.
i downloaded again the file, this time from this link:
https://ia800107.us.archive.org/27/items/stackexchange/
and i just managed to extract the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes downloaded files are "blocked" by the OS as a security measure. Right click the file you have downloaded and choose "Properties", you might see this:

[image: blocked file]

If that's the case, tick the "Unblock" checkbox, confirm, and it should work as expected.

Comment: there isn't an unblock checkbox. i was able to extract about 50% of the file...

Comment: @Matan cheers, so it's something else in your case. For me those blocks caused tons of problems in the past, as I keep forgetting about it. :)